# How to deserialize x-www-form-urlencoded to POJO/DTO or key/value map?

Tags: java, x-www-form-urlencoded

Does anyone know if there is any convenient way to take a x-www-form-urlencoded document as input (i.e., a string, or a stream) and deserialize it to either a POJO/DTO or a key/value map?

Comment: Sure, use Spring MVC. You need more details as to your operating environment.

Comment: The operating environment is as few dependencies as possible.  The goal is to take a string/stream as input and deserialize it to a POJO or key/value map. The application is not using Spring at all, thus it would be hard to justify dragging in Spring MVC as a dependency just to deserialize a string to a key-value pair.